# شركات سامسنج ارجا حل المشكله هذي بسرع وقت asseAhmad

Tags: google-assistant

شتريت مؤخرًا هاتف Samsung A21 مستعملًا ولكنه يخبرني دائمًا أنه "غير مسجل على الشبكة" وقد حاولت عدة مرات مسح البيانات الموجودة على Sim Toolkit وإعادة ضبط إعدادات الشبكة وإعادة ضبط المصنع ولكن لا شيء في النهاية. عندما اتصلت بالشخص الذي،  أخبرني شخص ما مرة أخرى أنه كان من الممكن أن يكون قد تم حظره من قبل الشركة المصنعة. الرجاء من أي شخص أن يساعدني في الحل

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] and post your question in English language. You may take help from a text translator service or a friend. Posts written in non-English languages are subject to closure and removal.